# Issue in closing JDBC Connection

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a jdbc connection which I'm trying to close but its returning a NullPointerException.

```
finally
    {
        try
        {
            if(load.dbConnection!=null)
            {
                load.dbConnection.close();
                LOGGER.info("Connection closed successfully");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            LOGGER.info("Exception is closing db connection"+e.getLocalizedMessage()+" "+e.getMessage()+" "+e.toString());

        }
    }
```

The stack trace is as shown:

```
Exception occured nullLevel [0] - File Name: 'loadData.java' Method Name: 'verifyFiles' Line Number: '896' Message: 'java.lang.Exception'
Level [1] - File Name: 'loadData.java' Method Name: '<init>' Line Number: '106' Message: 'java.lang.Exception'
Level [2] - File Name: 'loadData.java' Method Name: 'main' Line Number: '119' Message: 'java.lang.Exception'
```

I the above code I'm checking for null condition in spite of that why is the control entering the block and trying to close connection and also giving me a java.lang.NullPointerException.

```
//Initial assignment
loadData load = null;

    try
    {
    load = new loadData(); //Here the constructor calls 3 functions and exception occurs in one of those functions.

    }
    catch(Exception e){....}
    finally
    {
    //The finally code shown above
    }
```

SO in the above case when exception occurs in the constructor will the load remain null as shown in first assignment.

Comment: Please post a stack trace and specify which is the target line.

Comment: `load` is `null` (Or `LOGGER` is)

Comment: load may be null... LOGGER may be null...

Comment: @Brian,@Leo : I'll check the other conditions.

Comment: I think I hear Spring's JdbcTemplate calling out your name, Dark Matter.

Comment: @Dark Matter, could you provide a full code example with a whole stacktrace of Exception? Without it, I can only suggest to see the   [mkyong jdbc tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jdbc-tutorials/)

Comment: @Brian, @Leo: load was null, in that case `if(load.dbConnection!=null)` why does this return true and try to close the connection.

Comment: @DarkMatter, please, show the code from loadData.java. (There are nothing about a NullPointerException in your stacktrace)

Comment: @DarkMatter, do you resolve your problem?

Comment: @aurus: Yes, the load object assignment was not done successfully therefore connection object could not be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could only suggest to debug your code more carefully, something like this:

```
        //Initial assignment
        loadData load = null;
        System.out.println("logger is a null?: " + LOGGER);
        LOGGER.info("load: "+load);
        try
        {

            load = new loadData(); //Here the constructor calls 3 functions and exception occurs in one of those functions.
            LOGGER.info("load init: "+load);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            LOGGER.info("finally load: "+load);
            try
            {
                LOGGER.info("finally connection: " + load.dbConnection);
                if(load.dbConnection!=null)
                {
                    load.dbConnection.close();
                    LOGGER.info("Connection closed successfully");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```